# How does ImageMagick pass options to cwebp Linux

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, converters, webp

I'm running

```sh
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
```

I'm also running ImageMagick 6.9.

I'd like to convert a PDF image into WebP. AFAIK, out of the box, ImageMagick on Linux cannot convert to WebP, so I `sudo apt-get install webp` which installs `cwebp`.

`cwebp` allows to specify the `-q` parameter, and ImageMagick allows to specify the `-quality` parameter.

When I run `$ cwebp -q 90 image.png -o image.webp`, it takes `cwebp` around 8 seconds to convert it. If I run `convert image.png -quality 90 image.webp`, it takes ImageMagick around 30 seconds to convert it. It seems like the `-quality` parameter is not passed through to `cwebp`. It also may be the case that `convert` attempts to run a lossless conversion, which in `cwebp` is achieved with an explicit `-lossless` flag.

I run the test commands for a 10 MB test png image.

I would like to achieve 8 second conversion times with `convert` command. How can I do it?

Comment: To change arguments passed to webp, you can modify or create an entry in the delegates.xml file. See also https://imagemagick.org/script/webp.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that the delegates are invoked using the rules in `/etc/ImageMagick-6/delegates.xml`.

It lists a bunch of rules on how to convert between different types of images.

For my case, the `png`->`webp` conversion, I needed the string:
`<delegate decode="png" encode="webp" command="&quot;cwebp&quot; -quiet %Q &quot;%i&quot; -o &quot;%o&quot;"/>`

While in this file I don't know the `-quaility` parameter value, and there seems to be no way to capture it.

However, if you wish to keep the value of the `-q` parameter for `cwebp`, you have the option of hard-coding the `-q $YOUR_VALUE` right into the `command` inside the `delegate` tag.

This solution is still slower than invoking `cwebp` directly, since ImageMagick can take up to 8 seconds before invoking the delegate.

Answer (score 2):

I realize you want imagemagick, but if you are able to consider alternatives, [libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) can do pdf -> webp quickly at the command line, and without any configuring.

For example, with [this PDF (Audi R8 brochure)](https://www.audi.co.uk/content/dam/audi/production/PDF/PriceAndSpecGuides/r8.pdf) on my 2015 laptop, I see:

```
$ time convert -density 600 r8.pdf[3] -quality 90 x.webp
real    0m36.699s
user    0m23.787s
sys 0m1.628s
$ vipsheader x.webp
x.webp: 9921x4961 uchar, 3 bands, srgb, webpload
```

Which I think is broadly in line with the times you are seeing.

With libvips, I see:

```
$ time vips copy r8.pdf[dpi=600,page=3] x.webp[Q=90]
real    0m7.195s
user    0m6.861s
sys 0m0.505s
$ vipsheader x.webp
x.webp: 9921x4961 uchar, 3 bands, srgb, webpload
```

The same result, but within your 8s time budget.

You can set [a lot of other webp options](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/VipsForeignSave.html#vips-webpsave) if you want more control over compression.